# Custom middleware to inject headers from HttpClient response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, middleware

I'm building sort of a API Gateway.
The user send data to my API and I ask for an internal server about some data and them I send it back to the user.
My issue is that there are some headers that I should get from my HttpClient response and send it back to the client, it's simple, something like:

```
var response = await _httpClient.Client.GetAsync($"route" + query);
var responseBodyAsJson = HttpClientHelper.ExtractGenericJsonDocument(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
var cache = HttpClientHelper.ExtractCacheControl(response.Headers.CacheControl.ToString());
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(cache);
return responseBody;
```

This is already working, I removed the part were the json response is modified, and some other headers are read.
BUT there are 10 controllers routes now, and more will be added later. I don't want to need to write all of it all the time, and also someone may change it in the future and forget about the headers.

I tried to do a middleware like this:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
string cacheHeader = context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("cache-control", out var values) ? values.FirstOrDefault() : null;
var cache = HttpClientHelper.ExtractCacheControl(cacheHeader);
context.Response.Headers.Add(cache);
await _next(context);
}
```

But them I realized that the context which the middleware has access is the one I inject the headers manually.

So, is there a way that read the HttpClient Context Response and write it to the API Response for the whole app/path/controller ?

Comment: your middleware code is almost correct, just place the code ***after*** `_next(context)` and remember to place your middleware registration (`app.Use`) right before the mvc middleware (`app.UseMvc` in asp.net core 2.2). That ensures your middleware will have access to the response as soon as it comes out from the mvc middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe I didn't express myself correctly, but the middleware idea didn't work, even changing the _next position.
But no problem, managed to do it in another way.

I did a DI with the [IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-5.0) into my HttpClient class.
Keep in mind that you need to add it as a Singleton at Startup:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Them did something like this, inside my new public method inside my HttpClient class:

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(cache);
```

Finally my endpoints ended much cleaner, something like:

```
var response = await _httpClient.PrivateGetJsonAndInjectHeader($"route" + query);
return responseBody;
```

The result is not really "SOLID", since my new PrivateGetJsonAndInjectHeader get data, return the data, and also modify the main Context Headers, but still much cleaner, and should avoid any error. And also much easier to modify in the future, if needed.